# EFCore track record state: IsNew/IsLoaded

Tags: c#, ef-core-2.2

I just need to track if a record has been loaded from the database or is new.
The context is a WPF/EFCore 2.2.4 application.
One way could be testing if a record entry state in the 'active' DbContext, that is the DbContext that is handling the operation.
If a record is in the state Added (just added) or Detached (newly created and not yet added to the context), i can assume that is new.
But this works only under certain circumstances.

1. Records are never manually detached
2. Records are deleted from collection removing them from collections instead of calling remove from the context (because it puts them in detached state).

And there *can* be other cases that I can't immagine now.

To overcome this problem, when I first implemented the application I added in my base model an IsNew bool property. This 'explicit' approach should produce a fully knowable result.
Unfortunately it comes with shortcomings too.  EFCore requires a public constructor for entities that is used for loading entities. But nothing will prevent a developer from using it to create new entities.  So it cannot be used to set a state to IsLoaded, or IsNew = false or whatever.

Now I'm left with only 'second choice' approaches  that are: 
- setting IsNew after creation (providing false default)
- providing a static method that constructs and initializes properly IsNew

The second option would not be so bad if only i could make the constructor non-public.

Is out there any other better solution?

Comment: Is this before saving the added entity to database or can it be after saving also?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you're asking. If I use an IsNew field, it shoud be initialized to true for newly created records and it should switch to false when they are saved. On the other hand, when loading via EFCore, it should be set to false right after being loaded (even better should be as part of the loading, should an 'event' be available, something like 'after load').

Comment: Was just thinking about using primary key value to identify new. Before saving, it is a minus value so that  could identify them. Too simplistic?